# $timeout inside will loop creates infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout, splice

I cannot seem to get the timeout and the loop to work together. If I remove the loop it works or if I remove the timeout it will work. Together I will get an infinit loop and it doesnt seem like the timeout function ever runs if its inside of the while loop.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
function doTask (list) {
    if (list) {
        while (list.length > 0) {  
            (function(list){
                $timeout(function() {   
                   list.splice(0, 1); 
                   console.log("timeout...") 
                }, 5000); 
            })(list); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats because you are changing length in setTimeout which will get called after 5s but will land up not getting called as your code will never come out of loop

Comment: What you actually want to achive?

Comment: I would like to loop until the list is empty but delay the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use recursion to loop. Also, you should check `list.length` as `[]` is a true value.

```js
function doTask(list) {
  if (list.length) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      list.splice(0, 1);
      console.log("timeout...")
      doTask(list);
    }, 500);
  }
}
var list = [1,2,3,4,5]
doTask(list);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Your code never gives chance to run timeout function.**

When doTask is called it goes onto the stack for running. Now in each loop iteration, you are registering a timeout which will be executed when this doTask finishes. But you never gave chance for timeout to run hence the length of the list never decreased that's why it's running forever.

Hope this clarifies your query.